# Using session variable for load more

Tags: php, mysql, session

My issue is am using jQuery to auto refresh the div but am using the following script to keep the record track, so if the user clicks on Load More I load the posts, but the moment jQuery refreshes the div, it resets back to the default, any idea how do I preserve the number of loaded record

This is what I tried

```
if(isset($_POST['load_more'])) {
    $_SESSION['total_counter'] = $_SESSION['total_counter'] + 10;
    $fetch_messages = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT tbl_chat.record_date, msg_from, message, user_pic, tbl_chat.id, tbl_chat.record_date, real_name FROM tbl_chat JOIN tbl_users ON msg_from = tbl_users.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_SESSION['total_counter']);
} else {
    $counter = 10;
    $_SESSION['total_counter'] = $counter;
    $fetch_messages = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT tbl_chat.record_date, msg_from, message, user_pic, tbl_chat.id, tbl_chat.record_date, real_name FROM tbl_chat JOIN tbl_users ON msg_from = tbl_users.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_SESSION['total_counter']);
}
```

What happens is on refresh it uses the `$counter` value and forgets the load more session value

Detailed Code

```
<?php
    require_once 'connection.php';
    require_once 'functions.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || $_SESSION['logged_in'] == false) {
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery(".toggle_container").show();
                jQuery("div.question_trigger").click(function(){
                jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
                  $('.messages').load('chat.php .messages', function(){
                       $(this).fadeIn("fast")
                  });
            }, 2000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            require_once 'header.php';
            if($_SESSION['user_id'] == 1) {
                $clear_notifications = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE tbl_chat_notifications SET checked_first = 'yes' WHERE checked_first = ''");
            } elseif ($_SESSION['user_id'] == 2) {
                $clear_notifications = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE tbl_chat_notifications SET checked_second = 'yes' WHERE checked_second = ''");
            } elseif ($_SESSION['user_id'] == 3) {
                $clear_notifications = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE tbl_chat_notifications SET  checked_third = 'yes' WHERE checked_third = ''");
            }   
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST">
                <textarea name="messaging"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Post" name="message_input" class="gen_button" />
            </form>
            <img src="smileys/smile.gif" /><a target="_blank" href="smileys_info.php"> Smileys Info</a>
            <br /><br />
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['message_input'])) {
                $throw_error = array();
                if(isset($_POST['messaging']) && $_POST['messaging'] == '') {
                    $throw_error['msg_blank'] = "Message Cannot Be Blank";
                }

                if(empty($throw_error)) {
                    $message = nl2br(htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['messaging'])));
                    $date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    if(!mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO tbl_chat (msg_from, message, record_date) VALUES('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$message', '$date_time')")) {
                        echo mysqli_error($connection);
                    }

                    if($_SESSION['user_id'] == 1) {
                        if (!mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO tbl_chat_notifications (notification_of, checked_first) VALUES('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', 'yes')")) {
                            echo mysqli_error($connection);
                        } 
                    } elseif ($_SESSION['user_id'] == 2) {
                        if (!mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO tbl_chat_notifications (notification_of, checked_second) VALUES('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', 'yes')")) {
                            echo mysqli_error($connection);
                        }
                    } elseif ($_SESSION['user_id'] == 3) {
                        if (!mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO tbl_chat_notifications (notification_of, checked_third) VALUES('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', 'yes')")) {
                            echo mysqli_error($connection);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        header('Location: chat.php');
                        exit;
                    }
                }

                if(!empty($throw_error)) {
                    if(isset($throw_error['msg_blank'])) {
                        echo "<span class=\"red\">".$throw_error['msg_blank']."</span>";
                    }
                }
            }

            if(isset($_POST['load_more'])) {
                $_SESSION['total_counter'] = $_SESSION['total_counter'] + 10;
                $fetch_messages = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT tbl_chat.record_date, msg_from, message, user_pic, tbl_chat.id, tbl_chat.record_date, real_name FROM tbl_chat JOIN tbl_users ON msg_from = tbl_users.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_SESSION['total_counter']);

            } else {
                $counter = 10;
                $_SESSION['total_counter'] = $counter;
                $fetch_messages = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT tbl_chat.record_date, msg_from, message, user_pic, tbl_chat.id, tbl_chat.record_date, real_name FROM tbl_chat JOIN tbl_users ON msg_from = tbl_users.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_SESSION['total_counter']);
            }
            ?>
            <div class="messages">
            <?php
                while($throw_messages = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_messages)) {
            ?>
            <div class="message_container">
                <div class="display_pic">
                    <img src="<?php echo $throw_messages['user_pic']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="user_name">
                    <?php
                        echo $throw_messages['real_name'];
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="message"><?php smilies($throw_messages['message']); ?></div>
                <div class="msg_date_time"><?php echo explode_date_time($throw_messages['record_date']); ?></div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php
                if(mysqli_num_rows($fetch_messages) > 9) {
            ?>
            <form method="POST">
                <input type="submit" value="Load More" name="load_more" />
            </form>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got it, It was resetting the counter on page load because I was using tt was only adding up the value if the `load_more` form was submitted but as it was refreshed by jQuery it was resetting the counter value, this is the correct condition

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['total_counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['total_counter'] = 10;
}

if(isset($_POST['load_more'])) {
    $_SESSION['total_counter'] = $_SESSION['total_counter'] + 10;
    $fetch_messages = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT tbl_chat.record_date, msg_from, message, user_pic, tbl_chat.id, tbl_chat.record_date, real_name FROM tbl_chat JOIN tbl_users ON msg_from = tbl_users.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_SESSION['total_counter']);
} else {
    $fetch_messages = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT tbl_chat.record_date, msg_from, message, user_pic, tbl_chat.id, tbl_chat.record_date, real_name FROM tbl_chat JOIN tbl_users ON msg_from = tbl_users.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_SESSION['total_counter']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `session_start()` at the top of your script.

Comment: He might also need `isset()` on his session['total_counter'] assignment too.

Comment: Oh and SQL injection protection

Comment: @Neal that is obviously there, the only thing is it is getting resetted, am going wrong with the conditions, it is loading correctly, but moment it refreshes again the record goes back to 9 instead of 9+10

Comment: @Dave ehhh. mysqli won't excecute 2 queries at once. and the iffy part is in the limit of the query, so nothing really can be fudged with.

Comment: @Neal it's in the `connection.php`

Comment: @RandomGuy what am I? A psychic?

Comment: @Neal I never mentioned that you are, I told you everything is fine, I am not that novice, the only thing was conditions were wrong, it's the thing where I told you guys to focus, anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: He would have to be psychic to know you were not that novice :P